# regex expression to validate email which includes multiple "_" and "." symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I have this current regex expression to validate emails:

`^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w\\+]*[0-9a-zA-Z\\+])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$`

I want this to include "_" and "." to validate emails like these:

These are the valid emails that should pass/im validating:
`email@example.com`

`firstname.lastname@example.com`

`email@subdomain.example.com`

`firstname+lastname@example.com`

`Email@example.com`

`Email+book.28.feb@example.com`

`1234567890@example.com`

`email@example-one.com`

`_______@example.com`

`email@example.name`

`email@example.museum`

`email@example.co.jp`

`firstname-lastname@example.com`

I've tried adding `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` an underline here but doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can use `\w` as a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score -1):

***This should work:***

```
[\w.]+@\w+\.\w+
```

Comment: Where do I add this, could you give me the full line with this included, thanks alot

Comment: This is the whole regex...

Comment: Does not seem to work, this is what I have: 
``const emailValidationRegex = "[\w.]+@\w+\.\w+";``

Comment: I don't have information about what you are doing with that, I just showed you regex that works, you can check it here https://regex101.com/r/AMdvA9/1

Comment: Well, I have a list of emails that should be valid, they include uppercase, underscore, plus symbol and dots, this is it (I will post these in the original post above aswell):
``email@example.com``
``firstname.lastname@example.com``
``email@subdomain.example.com``
``firstname+lastname@example.com``
``Email@example.com``
``Email+book.28.feb@example.com``
``1234567890@example.com``
``email@example-one.com``
``_______@example.com``
``email@example.name``
``email@example.museum``
``email@example.co.jp``
``firstname-lastname@example.com``

Comment: Sorry man I cant help you, you are not being clear at all, there are examples of + also inside the email, you didn't mention it. But you can add a + inside the square brackets inside my regex and it will work. Otherwise I don't know what to say.